# How to Define CSS for Elements inside Shiny Modules

Tags: jquery, html, r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm trying to achieve the following result in HTML using shiny Module:

Outside shiny module:
p tag is black, when hover mouse over the it, cursor should be changed to pointer and color should be changed grey.

Inside shiny module:
p tag is blue, when hover mouse over it, cursor should be changed to pointer and color should be changed to red.

The HTML version works:
[demo](https://codepen.io/yusuzech/pen/GVyNGY)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        p{color:black;}
        p:hover{color:grey;cursor:pointer;}

        #mymodule p{color:blue;}
        #mymodule p:hover{color:red;cursor:pointer;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>text outside module</p>
    <div id='mymodule'>
        <p>text inside module</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
    <p>some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add CSS for the module, but it seems like it doesn't work. What should I do? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```r
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(shinyjs)

mymoduleUI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    uiOutput(ns("text"))
}

mymodule <- function(input,output,session,color,colorHover){
    id <- session$ns("mymoduleUI")
    css_text <- glue("#{id} p{{color:{color};}}
                    #{id} p:hover{{color:{colorHover};}}")
    print(css_text)
    output$text <- renderUI({
        shinyjs::inlineCSS(rules = css_text)
        tags$p("text inside module")
    })
}


shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
        tags$head(tags$style("p{color:balck;}
                             p:hover{color:grey}")),
        tags$p("text outside module"),
        mymoduleUI("here")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        callModule(module = mymodule,id = 'here',color="blue",colorHover="red")
    }
)
```

Comment: Is the omission of `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` because you don't need javascript interaction? ([`?useShinyjs`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyjs/versions/1.0/topics/useShinyjs) does say it must be loaded *"for all other 'shinyjs' functions to work"*. \*shrug\*)

Comment: I deleted that line, the line is not needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were the following errors:

1. As pointed out by *r2evans*, `useShinyjs()` statement was missing
2. Use `session$ns("text")` instead of `session$ns("mymoduleUI")`. The id of the `uiOutput` is `'here-text'`, but the original version returns `'here-mymoduleUI'`.
3. If you set the `css` about the same time as you create the element it won't apply, as the element doesn't even exist by then.

If there can be numerous instances of this module each with different `css` I would recommend attaching `css` rules to the `head` as seen below. Otherwise if there were only a certain amount of options (e.g.: color: red, blue, green), then I would create `css classes` beforehand, and use `class = ...`.

#### Code:

```
mymodule <- function(input,output,session,color,colorHover){
  id <- session$ns("text")

  css_text <- glue("
    $('head').append('<style type=\"text/css\">#{id} p{{color:{color}}} #{id} p:hover{{ color:{colorHover}}}</style>');
  ")
  print(css_text)
  output$text <- renderUI({
    tags$p("text inside module")
  })

  observe( {
    shinyjs::runjs(css_text)
  })
}
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your second approach?